# How do you learn GLove word vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, word-embeddings

$X_{ik} = \# $ times work $i$ occurs in the context of work $k$. $X_i$ is the number of times word $i$ occurs. $P_{ik} = \frac{X_{ik}}{X_i}$.

It's not clear to me what equation 3 solves and why the solution to (4) is $F=exp$.

Glove Paper: http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf
[image]

Comment: Please explain what the $w_i$ and $\tilde w_i$ are and what the objective of this analysis is.

Comment: The $w_i$'s are word vectors.